# Postgres how to determine there are X records spanning 2 days of datetimes in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table containing electricity meter readings which looks something like this:

```
| meter_id | reading_interval_datetime |
| 110      | 2018-01-15T00:00:00+00:00 |
| 110      | 2018-01-15T00:30:00+00:00 |
```

The table is filled with at most 48 records per day (one reading every 30 mins).

What's an efficient way to check if a particular meter has at least two days of readings in there?

Comment: What does "two days of reading in there" mean?  Please provide more details on what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine if a `meter_id` has at least two days by doing:

```
select meter_id
from t
group by meter_id
having min(reading_interval_datetime::date) <> max(reading_interval_datetime::date);
```

This will check that there are two dates in the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
sql> create index your_table_idx on your_table(meter_id, date(reading_interval_datetime));
sql> select meter_id, date(reading_interval_datetime), count(1)
       from your_table
      where meter_id = THE_METER_ID_YOUD_LIKE_TO_CHECK
      group by meter_id, date(reading_interval_datetime)
     having count(1) > 1
```